# Force Missile Mage: Overpowering Missile vs Reflective Shield?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

A slightly oddball question. Let's say I have two Sorc 10/ Force Missile Mage 5. Let's just say.

They both have Overpowering Missile:

> **Overpowering Missile**: At third level, the force missile mage's *magic missile* spells
>   become especially potent, breaking through spell resistance more readily than normal.
>   She gains a +2 bonus on caster level checks to overcome a creature's sell resistance with
>   the spell *magic missile*. This benefit only applies to *magic missile* spells she casts.
>   In addition, a force missile mage's *magic missiles* penetrate *shield* spells and *brooches of
>   shielding* as if they didn't offer protection from the spell.

and, they both have *Reflective Shield*:

> ***Reflective Shield (Sp)***: At fourth level, a force missile mage becomes immune to the
>   spell *magic missile*. For the purposes of being affected by *magic missile*, a force missile
>   mage is constantly treated as under the effect of *spell turning*, thus reflecting offensive
>   *magic missiles* back at their caster. If that caster is protected by the *shield* spell or a
>   *brooch of shielding* these reflected missiles are negated. Missiles reflected against a
>   caster who also has a *spell turning* in effect require the force missile mage to roll on the
>   *spell turning* mishap chart (PHB 283).

So, given that they are throwing Magic Missiles at each other (they're not all that bright), how would they interact? Would they function as normal, would both players have to roll on the *spell turning* mishap chart, or would they just cancel everything out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on whether or not either or both of them has *shield* (or similar) active.

### Case 1: Neither has *shield* active

With no *shield* spells in play, Overpowering Missile does not come into play at all. Reflective Shield does not replicate the effects of the *shield* spell, and only refers to that spell when it is active on *the other guy*.

Instead, the situation is identical to if both of them had an infinite version of *spell turning* active: a resonating field is created, and you have to roll on the chart.

### Case 2: One has *shield* active

The one with *shield* active has his own missiles, turned by his opponent’s Reflective Shield, negated by his *shield* spell. The missiles turned by Reflective Shield are explicitly negated by *shield* or similar, which trumps the caster’s own Overpowering Missile feature (specific trumps general: his *magic missiles* generally ignore *shield*, but Reflective Shield specifically says the turned missiles don’t ignore *shield*).

The one without *shield* overcomes his opponent’s *shield* due to Overpowering Missile, but then the *magic missile* is turned by Reflective Shield. He has his own Reflective Shield, so you get the same resonating field as you did in Case 1, but only on his turn rather than for both their turns.

### Case 3: Both have *shield* active

The *shield* on each of them negates their own turned *magic missiles*, and so a resonating field never occurs. They are literally burning spell slots to no effect.

Comment: I don't think the class designer took into account having two FMMs duking it out though. Overpowering Missile places the effect on the spell, and then Reflective Shield takes it away, even though it would not do such a thing to a normal Magic Missile spell? I dunno on that front. Good point that Reflective Shield isn't actually a Shield spell, though. Not entirely sure why I thought it would be a similar effect.

Comment: @Phill.Zitt: I agree they probably didn't think things through, but the errata rules are very clear on how these kinds of things work. Reflective Shield is functionally an exception to the general case for Overpowering Shield, by RAW anyway. Put another way, Reflective Shield's turned *magic missiles* would be negated by *shield* **even if *shield* didn't normally do that for anyone.**